# Multiple renders of jinja2 templates?

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there any way to do this with jinja2?

```
template = Template("{{ var1 }}{{ var2 }}")
rendered1 = template.render(var1=5) # "5-{{ var2 }}"
rendered2 = Template(rendered1).render(var2=6) # "5-6"
```

basically, I want to be able to do multiple passes on a template. When the template engine finds a variable in the template that is not in the context, instead of replacing it with nothing, keep the template variable intact? If not jinja2, is there any other python template library that can do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [DebugUndefined](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.DebugUndefined), which keeps the failed lookups, as your [Undefined Type](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#undefined-types) for the `undefined` parameter of the `Template` environment:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template, DebugUndefined
>>> template = Template("{{ var1 }}-{{ var2 }}", undefined=DebugUndefined)
>>> rendered1 = template.render(var1=5) # "5-{{ var2 }}"
>>> print(rendered1)
5-{{ var2 }}
>>> rendered2 = Template(rendered1).render(var2=6) # "5-6"
>>> print(rendered2)
5-6
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, DebugUndefined has several bugs today: 1) undefined variable's fields throw an error, https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/811 2) DebugUndefined does not show custom delimiters https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/958 .